# Average For Previous Month and YTD in Previous Month DAX

Tags: date, powerbi, dax

Both PREVIOUSMONTH and DATEADD are not working.

I am trying to show the Average of “Actual Duration” for Previous Month in a table “VMC based on Project Completion Date”. I need a dynamic measure.

As the date column does not show every day (meaning a row is created if there was activity that day) my understanding was that I need a Calendar Date table to use PREVIOUSMONTH or DATEADD. I have created a table "Dates" with a column "Date" from 1/01/2018 to 31/12/2021.

I have created relationship between two tables.

This is the measure I am trying to create:

```
AVG in PM = 
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE('VMC based on Project Completion Date'[Actual Duration]),
    PREVIOUSMONTH(Dates[Date])
)
```

I get blank result.

[image]

I also need to create a measure showing the YTD result in a Previous Month.

This is what I wrote:

```
Cycle Time = 
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE('VMC based on Project Completion Date'[Actual Duration]),
    DATEADD(Dates[Date].[Date], -1,MONTH)
)
```

It does show the Average  of 154 which is a current YTD. But as it is April now and I had no transaction for April I could not say if the measure shows YTD for March.

However, when I checked what was YTD result two months ago.

```
Cycle Time = 
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE('VMC based on Project Completion Date'[Actual Duration]),
    DATEADD(Dates[Date].[Date], -2,MONTH)
)
```

The result was still the same 132.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

```
AVG in PM = 
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE('VMC based on Project Completion Date'[Actual Duration]),
    PREVIOUSMONTH(Dates[Date])
)
```

```
Cycle Time = 
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE('VMC based on Project Completion Date'[Actual Duration]),
    DATEADD(Dates[Date].[Date], -1,MONTH)
)
```

Comment: Can you post an image of the visual where you tested your "Cycle Time" measure and it returned blank?

Comment: @RADO I have added the link to the image of the card.